# NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy not giving expected result

Tags: ios, nsdecimalnumber

I am facing an issue with `NSDecimalNumber`. I have code similar to the one below.

```
NSDecimalNumber *n1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: @"1e-80"];
NSDecimalNumber *n2 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: @"1e-80"];
NSDecimalNumber *n3 = [n1 decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy: n2 withBehavior: [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode: NSRoundPlain
                                                                             scale: 127
                                                                  raiseOnExactness: TRUE
                                                                   raiseOnOverflow: TRUE
                                                                  raiseOnUnderflow: TRUE
                                                               raiseOnDivideByZero: TRUE]];
NSLog(@"result=%@", [n3 descriptionWithLocale: [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]]);
```

The above code is printing the result `1e+98`, which is incorrect; it should be zero. What am I missing here?

Comment: Interesting.  Empirically, the concept works up `[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1e-64"]` but then behavior reverts to pattern you notice.  Something to do with internal representation of `NSDecimalNumber`?

Comment: The number is probably just too small for the way decimal numbers work.  Why would you want to use number as small as 1e-80? What possible real world significance could such a number have?

Comment: Small numbers are important for people working in physics or similar areas. I am working on App which deals with very small numbers.